# How to create an unordered list of images separate from the content

Tags: php, images

Some of the solutions I'd tried are 'multiple featured images,' and 'upload image gallery,' but they're either require plugins, are too convoluted, or make for terrible html syntax.

I've looked around at websites that use wordpress, and found [this](http://htarchitecte.com/en/projects/joliette-elementary-school/), and would like to know how they might have coded their list of images at the bottom of their 'Projects' post in the backend:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using Wordpress *custom fields*.

You can add them using the Wordpress API or using a plugin like **Advanced Custom Fields**

If so, create a **Repeater field** that contains **Image field**.

Use [this](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/) to show your repeater field.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I will try the custom fields, but would rather not use any plugin, and instead the API, but I don't know in what manner I ought to. Should I create an entirely new custom post type to display a list of images for every post, or should I use the 'upload gallery' feature, or...?